# Why do images automatically fit in a container with flex-direction column, but not row?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `flex` container with `flex-direction: column`:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

and an image inside it:

```
   <div>
        <img src="https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/learn/images/balloons.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

the image is scaled down to fit inside the container:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/learn/images/balloons.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
```

but with `flex-direction: row` this doesn't happen.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 30px;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}


img {
flex-shrink: 0
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/learn/images/balloons.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
```

Why does `flex-direction: column` auto fit the image in the container?

Comment: With those css rules, your image is *proportionally* scaled until it hits the left and bottom border of the div, in first and second cases, respectively. Because the aspect ratios of your image and div are different, you get such results. Try an image where height is longer than width and you will get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the stretch default alignment. When using `column` the stretch force the image to fill all the horizontal space. The same happen with `row` direction by the way but the image overflow on the other direction.

You can disable this if you update the alignment:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start; /* added */
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 0
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/learn/images/balloons.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
```

If you use the opposite ratio for your image, you will get the opposite effect

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 0
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div style="flex-direction: column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
```

As you can see in both of the cases, we have a stretch in on direction and for the other one it depends on the image. Either the image fit inside the container or we have an overflow.

If you update the alignment you will get an overflow in both cases:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 0
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div style="flex-direction: column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `flex-direction: column` the width of the image is automatically constrained to the container's width.

In `flex-direction: row` there is no such constraint, and the image is free to overflow the container.

The simple solution is to apply `width: 100%` to the image.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/learn/images/balloons.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Aspect ratio and `object-fit` are other matters.